# Aggregate JSON fields in Postgres 9.3

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a JSON column, named info, with these values:

```
    {"width":"800, "height":"480"}
    {"width":"800, "height":"480"}
    {"width":"768, "height":"480"}
```

I need a SQL query to have the output in this format:

```
    Label   |Count
    ==============
    800x480, 2
    768x480, 1
```

Where the second value represents the count.

What I managed to do is to extract first value and the count:

```
    select info->>'width' as label, count(info->>'width') from table_name  GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 5
```

Which outputs:

```
    Label   |Count
    ==============
    800, 2
    768, 1
```

Comment: suggest question should be concatenate and not aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular [string concatenation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html) should do it. For some reasons, the query fails if you omit the `()` from the query.

```
SELECT (info->>'width') || 'x' || (info->>'width') AS label,
    COUNT(info->>'width')
FROM table_name
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 5
```